# Q: How to configure Apache in official Wordpress Container behind NGINX SSL reverse proxy

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, reverse-proxy, bad-request

I've installed a Wordpress container (wordpress official, latest image, contains Apache and MySQL), which is working fine in its local environment (192.168.xxx.xxx). No extra configuration, all out of the box. No SSL, plain HTTP.

I also have an SSL NGINX reverse proxy (letsencrypt) installed, which is working fine with other SSL/HTTPS stuff (website within NGINX, NextCloud, 2 Ghost blogs, etc).

I was assuming that getting WP hooked up via my reverse proxy was a piece of cake, but I was wrong. I'm at it for almost two days now and it is really doing my head in. I found loads of stuff on the internet and on this site, but none of it was really of help.

I'm getting 'Bad Request' responses and I don't know how to get beyond this point.

The below seems to be a bit much, but I tried to be as concise as possible.

My goal:

Get WP working in HTTP mode behind the SSL reverse proxy.

My setup:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somepassword
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: somepassword

   wordpress:
     links:
       - db
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "32768:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       VIRTUAL_HOST: sub.domain.tld
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: somepassword
volumes:
    db_data:
```

As mentioned before, the above is installed with docker-compose and it works right away with `http://192.168.xxx.xxx:32768`.

My NGINX reverse proxy is on a different server. It is also a docker container, installed with this docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3'  
services:
  app:
    restart: always
    privileged: true
    image: linuxserver/letsencrypt
    container_name: letsencrypt
    ports:
      - "8088:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./letsencrypt:/config
    environment:
      - URL=domain.tld
      - SUBDOMAINS=sub1,sub2,sub3
      - VALIDATION=http
      - DHLEVEL=2048
      - EMAIL=my@email.addr
      - ONLY_SUBDOMAINS=true
      - EXTRA_DOMAINS=sub.otherdomain.tld
```

This works with a number of other services, so I consider this to be ok.

I've then created a site-config for the wp subdomain:

```
upstream wp {
    server 192.168.xxx.xxx:32768;
    keepalive 64;
 }

server {  
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name sub.otherdomain.tld;

#    root /var/www/html;
#    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    ###SSL Certificates
    ssl_certificate /config/keys/letsencrypt/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /config/keys/letsencrypt/privkey.pem;

    ###DiffieñHellman key exchange ###
    ssl_dhparam /config/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    ###SSL Ciphers
    ssl_ciphers .....;

    ###Extra Settings###
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ### Add HTTP Strict Transport Security ###
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains";


      location / {
        include /config/nginx/proxy.conf;

        proxy_pass http://wp;

#        pass to HTTP test server
#        proxy_pass http://192.168.xxx.xxx:80;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded_For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header HTTPS "on";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

All of the above is what I have configured. Additionally, I have set the [WP URLs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCtov.jpg) accordingly. What I have NOT done are any modifications within the WP container. I would expect, that WP handles any Apache settings by itself, so that no further configuration is required.

So, the above results in a [Bad Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93TY9.jpg).

Since I couldn't get it to work, I changed the `proxy_pass` away from the WP service to an idle HTTP test server (just another nginx container on yet another server).

```
#        proxy_pass http://wp;

#        pass to HTTP test server
        proxy_pass http://192.168.xxx.xxx:80;
```

I wrote a small PHP script, which shows me the header of the incoming request:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept-Language: de-de
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/601.7.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1.3 Safari/601.7.8
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Https: on
X-Nginx-Proxy: true
X-Forwarded-Host: sub.otherdomain.tld
X-Forwarded-Server: sub.otherdomain.tld
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
X-Forwarded-For: 80.147.xxx.xxx
X-Real-Ip: 80.147.xxx.xxx
Host: sub.otherdomain.tld
```

Please note, that I've tried this with FireFox and Chrome, so not just the old version of Safari used for this test. Same results, through.

My preliminary conclusion: The reverse proxy settings and the SSL certificates are intact. I can access the HTTP server through the SSL reverse proxy from the internet without any errors.

My assumption now is, that the reverse proxy is good. Also, WP is good. At least locally via the internal IP address. The bit which I might be missing is Apache, which is sitting between my proxy and WP.

Also note, that I found loads of stuff about modifying `.htaccess`, but from what I learned, those bits were already implemented in the latest WP image.

```
root@57f2961f7428:/var/www/html# cat .htaccess
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Question is: Is there anything I need to configure in Apache within the WP container? 000-default.conf?

How can I get through to WP via my SSL reverse proxy?

Regards

Carsten